# Selecting a dynamic drop down item in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a dynamic drop down menu and I want to select one of the items within it. 
I have tried using the Select method but I believe that it doesn't work because the drop down isn't a select item. So instead, I think the solution would be to first click the drop down and then search for the item I want to select.

The drop down looks like this:

[image: Here]

The drop down after it's been clicked looks like this:

[image: Here]

The HTML code:

[image: Here]

I have tried getting my Python script to click the drop down so that it expands but I believe I must be using the wrong ID (`s2_id_autogen10_search`). Any help or any other solution ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT:

So I am now trying to get Selenium to click the listbox to expand the options. Given the HTML code below, I am trying:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("select2-results-10").click()
```

However, it is not working. I receive this error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element 
not interactable
```

Comment: I would try using `//ul[@class='select2-results']/li[.='text_goes_here']`. Make sure to use the webDriverWait and clickable.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page you are working with?

Comment: You should also post the current code you are using and why it's not working, e.g. throws an exception (post the exception in your question) or describe what isn't working.

Comment: @JeffC have just updated original post.